# NodeJS won't run in any new directory

Tags: node.js

I'm started using NodeJS about 10 months ago, never had any error that I can't figure out by myself untill now. I do get this error even with only 1 line like `const fs = require('fs');`

```
PS C:\NodeJS-Scripting\path> node .
C:\NodeJS-Scripting\path\gulpfile.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ��/
                                                          ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:152:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:605:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:682:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:613:3
PS C:\NodeJS-Scripting\path>
```

useful info?

- NodeJS: v9.2.0
- NPM: v5.5.1
- OS: Win10 Pro
- OS Build: 15063.726

Comment: Can you also add what is written in gulpfile.js?

Comment: as I said, with only this line, I get the same error: `const fs = require('fs');`

Comment: I should maybe tell you that gulpfile.js is just like app.js or index.js, I tried the same setup in another path first both with and and without gulp, then I copied the files into the path where I copied the error code from.

I can try to create yet another path where I only add a new index.js and just do `console.log("it works");` to confirm if it's something with NodeJS or something I may have done wrong

Comment: Do you see these `��/` on that line. Maybe these characters explain your problem.

Comment: I don't even know why or where they appear. I've repeted that even with only a simple line that I've used in multiple working scripts ends with the same error. I do normally find all my problems here at Stack Overflow, but this problem makes me really confused because even when all my code is commented, I get the same error

Comment: I still don't really know the actual issue, but by creating a new file in the exact same path named index.js, copy/pasting the code part by part and run the script works, but running the gulpfile.js still doesn't work